# Visual Studio Code "Open With Code" does not appear after right-clicking a folder

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-code, windows-7-x64

Just installed Visual Studio Code 1.1.1 on a Windows 7 machine. When I right-click on a folder, "Open With Code" does not appear.

[image]

Comment: Please edit this post so that it asks a question. It is currently impossible to decide which answers to upvote because I cannot tell which are answering the (assumed) question properly.

Answer (score 201):

Copied from [Right click on Windows folder and open with Visual Studio Code](http://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/)

- Create file **vsCodeOpenFolder.reg** with this content (If you didn't choose the default installation path then you need to adjust the paths in this file):

  ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   ; Open files
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
   @="Edit with VS Code"
   "Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
   @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
   ; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
   ; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
   @="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
   "Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
   @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
   ; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
   ; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
   @="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
   "Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
   @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
  ```
- Double click it to create the registry entries.
- If the "Open with Code" doesn't appear in the Explorer's context menu then you should restart your system.
- If you're running the 64-bit or Insiders version of VS Code, change the path accordingly. ie. `C:\\Users\\[user_name]\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe`

Comment: I've never been able to get this to work under a user account. But it works for admin accounts.

Comment: Obviously this isn't required for all those keys are already set in my case. Still there is no entry in context menu unless working as admin user required before for installing VS Code into global folder. Thus it looks like VS code either isn't design to run on a multi-user system or fails to support use case of working as a non-administrative user. Is it 2002 and XP has been released as next big thing or is it 2017 and people have been engaged to stop working as admins since Vista? What if Microsoft fails to properly support its own operating system?

Comment: @wosi how can we delete the option if needed?

Comment: @CalvinDale, Open cmd as administrator, paste in prompt full path of the .reg file, Enter, confirm all. Done.

Comment: Now that Code 64-bit is available, this works just as well replacing all occurrences of " (x86)" with "". Or in other words, change "Program Files (x86)" to "Program Files".

Comment: For those transferring this for other use cases: The difference between the context menues `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode` is weather you click on a certain dictory or on "nothing" (you're always in a directory in win explorer)

Comment: Even the given source states "It’s easier to simply re-install VS Code.": These options are in the installation process

Comment: @eddow Sometimes you just have to scratch your right ear with your left foot

Comment: Glad it worked, had to update the path accordingly though. Reinstalling VsCode didn't solve it for me so this was the only solution.

Comment: YOUR SOLUTION CRASHED MY OPERATING SYSTEM, USELESS, NOW I WILL HAVE TO WASTE 3-4 HOURS OF MY LIFE TO SETUP OPERATING SYSTEM AND OTHER APPLICATIONS. USELESS, USELESS, USELESS...

Comment: Awesome, this still works in 2023 for VS Code 32-bit!

Comment: When double clicking the file I get "Cannot import [PATH_TO_vsCodeOpenFolder.reg] Error accesing the registry"

Answer (score 146):

When installing (or reinstall and) check all checkBoxes especially:

> Add "Open with Code" action to Windows Explorer file context menu
> Add "Open with Code" action to Windows Explorer directory context menu

[image: install vscode]

Comment: Re-installed and made sure to check the options - fixed for me

Comment: @ar This works _if_ you are logged-in as an **admin** user--it doesn't work if you are not in the administrators group (good practice for security reasons).

Comment: good thing is you can simply install over it, no need to first uninstall!

Comment: Unfortunately for me, my workplace deploys VSCode via Software Center, so the settings are already chosen for me.

Comment: I reactivated an 11 year old stack exchange account to upvote this

Answer (score 44):

In my case, I just re-run the vscode setup and marked all checkboxes as checked and It worked.[image]

Comment: This is exactly the recommended way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, don't both with the Regedit solution, this one takes about 1 minute to do.

Answer (score 42):

Here comes the version of file provided by Cockney Rhyming Jedi before suitable for use with **64-bit version** of Visual Studio Code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open files
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Edit with VS Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Comment: Obviously integrated updater tends to remove this patch occasionally, so I have to re-apply it after upgrading VS code.

Comment: After using this version I did get the new option "Open folder as VS Code project" - but no simple "Open in VS Code". What am I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @JonSnow you can simply change the text present after @= to whatever you like. Instead of @="Open Folder as VS Code Project", you can say @="Open with JonSnow's Editor"  ..lol

Comment: I notice this version updates HKEY_CURRENT_USER, as opposed to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in Wosi's answer.  Does that mean using this version you could make the registry changes without being a member of the local administrator's group on the machine?

Comment: @SimonElms I'd assume so. This root key and its thread is writable by current user.

Answer (score 30):

If you have vscode installed already and you want the "open with code" option.

Just download vscode from the official website...
[here](https://code.visualstudio.com/)!

Run the installer with the option "open with code" checked.

It will update the existing vscode install with the "open with code" option.

Comment: This option should be the top answer!

Comment: I think reinstalling the vscode is the best answer. Adding reg data possibly gone wrong

Comment: what if I don't have admin accesS?

Answer (score 26):

I'd like to add that, many would like to go for the Registry method because they are afraid they might loose all their settings. Just re-download(if you don't already have the download file ) and reinstall. When reinstalling, tick

```
Add "Open with Code" action to Windows Explorer file context menu
Add "Open with Code" action to Windows Explorer directory context menu
```

as already said in other answers. Your settings will remain intact. In fact, when it launches, it launches with your working directory as if you never uninstalled it.

Comment: Well, I've tried this so many times for months but that never made it work for me as this option was ticked and still it doesn't add those options to _my_ context menu, but the context menu of admin user I was required to switch to for installation, only. You are missing an essential point of this problem. In addition I don't think people going to patch registry are considering uninstalling some software might drop its settings implicitly.

Comment: I don't really get your comment but to elaborate on my answer further, what I'm trying to say is that, maybe someone would like to choose to tweak the settings in the Registry because they might think that, uninstalling their VS code will restore their custom settings to default after they reinstall. My answer is an assurance that, if you uninstall and reinstall the program, your settings will still remain intact.

Comment: You don't even have to uninstall. Just download the installer, run it and it installs on top of the existing installation. I think it's the uninstall that people are afraid of. I just did this a few minutes ago and it works; all settings and plugins intact.

Answer (score 23):

my vscode installed here:

```
C:\Users\saber\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe
```

**should replace SABER with your pc username**

[image]

so the script is s.th like  this:

save this content as a *.reg file

then run it :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Open files
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Edit with VS Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\saber\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\saber\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\saber\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\saber\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\saber\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\saber\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

add visual studio code to right click folder in windows

replace the `\\saber\\` with `\\YOUR_PC_USER_NAME\\`

Comment: use your folder name instead of saber in this file

Comment: This path of vs code is when you install from Microsoft store.

Answer (score 19):

These settings are normally stored per-user for VS Code.

To set for a new user account: re-run the installer.

Answer (score 16):

NB:  This is for the **32-bit version**, for the 64-bit version see Cepharum's answer.

Slight change to the previous answer to allow non Admins to get the functionality in their context menus:

- Create file vsCodeOpenFolder.reg with this content (If you didn't chose the default installation path then you need to adjust the paths in this file):

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
  ; Open files
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
  @="Edit with VS Code"
  "Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
  @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
  ; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
  ; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode]
  @="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
  "Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
  @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
  ; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
  ; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
  @="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
  "Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
  @="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
  ```
- Double click it to create the registry entries
- If the "Open with Code" doesn't appear in the Explorer's context menu then you should restart your system.

Essentially I have replaced HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes

Comment: Thanks for this fix. Glad to see I'm not the only one trying to work with administrative privileges as little as possible.

Answer (score 12):

None of the registry entries above worked for me with a standard (non-admin) user account.

I then inserted all the keys into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and then it worked!

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; when you right click a file
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\VSCode]
@="Open with Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""

; when you right click a folder
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\VSCode]
@="Open Folder in Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""

; when you right click a folder while holding shift
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode]
@="Open Folder in Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""

; when you right click the background, not on a particular file or folder.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\LibraryFolder\Background\shell\VSCode]
@="Open Folder in Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\LibraryFolder\Background\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Answer (score 9):

If you prefer using the keyboard more than the mouse. This solution is for you...

Type the following commands in your file explorer (location).

**Open a project**

```
vscode://file/{full path to project}/

vscode://file/c:/myProject/

vscode:// --opens vscode for current directory
```

**Open a file**

```
vscode://file/{full path to file}

vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json
```

**Open a file to line and column**

```
vscode://file/{full path to file}:line:column

vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json:5:10
```

**Source**: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just run the installer again with `open in file explorer` option selected. You'll be all set.

**Don't worry about the files already opened in vsCode, none of them will be changed**

Answer (score 7):

if you have **windows 11**, don't want to mess up with the registry and don't want to wait for the next updates, just hold down **shift** while **right clicking** on a folder or file.

Comment: This is an underrated comment.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Reinstall *Visual Studio Code* from [the official website](https://code.visualstudio.com), There won't be any data loss.

Just make sure this time to enable those options in the installer:

[image]

It just adds the "Open with Code" option after *right-clicking* in/on the folder.

But if still doesn't appear:

[image]

You just need to click on *"Show more options"* Or shortly with combination of keyboard stroke <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Paste the code below and save with **.reg** extension

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 ; Open files

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code] @="Edit with VS Code" 

"Icon"="C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe,0" 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command] 

@="\"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" \"%1\"" 
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder 

; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode] 
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"

"Icon"="\"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe",0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode\command]

@="\"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" \"%1\"" 

; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder ; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]

@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"

"Icon"="\"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe",0

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]

@="\"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" \"%V\""
```

Then press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, locate Visual Studio Code, then right click and open file the location:

[image: open vscode location]

Right click and click <kbd>Properties</kbd>, then copy the file path.

[image]

Open `regedit`:

[image: reg edit]

For each of the following, double click on the icon, and paste the file path you copied from above:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
```

[image]

Comment: There were severe formatting issues with your RegEx file and locations that would have prevented this from working. Notably, your `*.reg` file had `>` at the beginning of each line, and had contents wrapped in a way that I believe would have caused issues on import. Further, your registry paths were really inconsistent, with some using `>` or even `-->` as the path delimiters. I've updated this to help prevent these issues; please review my changes carefully to make sure they capture your intent. In the future, though, please put more care into your formatting and code to ensure it works.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyCaney for the correction. I'm new to the editor used for answering here. Will surely take note of the errors in future posts.

Answer (score 4):

- 

> I used 64bit VS Code installer

> copy and paste this codes into your pc notepad

> save as vscode.reg

> then open and merge that saved file. happy coding.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open files

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Edit with VS Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""


; This will handle right clicking on a folder and open that folder
; as a new project

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""

; This handles the case of right clicking inside of a folder
; to open that folder as a new project

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with earlier version of VS code 64 bit. It didn't work even after I re-installed by checking the above mentioned options.

I have installed the latest update of code v1.25.0, and the issue was automatically fixed.

[image: vs code version]

Please find the 64 bit regedit fix [here](http://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/).

Comment: The reg file at the linked location worked for me on Win 10 64 bit after adjusting for personalised installation path.

Answer (score 3):

Just re run the installer and select the options in the setup and let it install. You'll not loose any data. Everything will be still intact as it was before. It just adds the missing settings and updates the path.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest solution was to download Visual Studio Code, and reinstall it again.

[image]

Then check the boxes that says "Open with Code"

Answer (score 2):

This questions already has a lot of answers but here is one that will work for any user if VS Code installation folder is in the user's AppData folder, no changing the user name required!

It is based on the original idea by Dave Johnson [here](http://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/), and the answer of @Wosi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306672/visual-studio-code-open-with-code-does-not-appear-after-right-clicking-a-folde/37306940#37306940), among others in this thread.

I used the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable (recognized only in the user context, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables)) which refers to `C:\\Users\<username>`.

For environment variables to be expanded from Registry values, the values must be of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` (including the `Default` value of the keys if they also contain environment variables), and values of this type are not stored as classic text in a .reg file, but as a hex data format. I created the `Default` values for the new keys with the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type using another key I exported to a .reg to avoid using commands (even if I think `REG_SZ` would have been enough for them in this particular case). See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1682273/creating-registry-key-with-expandable-string-value-named-default/1682294#1682294) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/422672/adding-userprofile-to-a-command-in-the-windows-registry/422679#422679).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Open files

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCode]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,77,00,26,00,69,00,74,00,68,00,20,00,43,\
  00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,00,00
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,4c,00,\
  6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,\
  00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,\
  53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,\
  00,78,00,65,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCode\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,4c,00,\
  6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,\
  00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,\
  53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,\
  00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\VSCode]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,46,00,6f,00,6c,00,64,00,65,00,72,00,20,\
  00,61,00,73,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,20,00,50,00,\
  72,00,6f,00,6a,00,65,00,63,00,74,00,00,00
"Icon"=hex(2):22,00,25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,\
  00,4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,\
  4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,\
  00,73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,\
  56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,\
  00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,2c,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\VSCode\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,4c,00,\
  6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,\
  00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,\
  53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,\
  00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,31,00,22,00,00,00

; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode]
@=hex(2):4f,00,70,00,65,00,6e,00,20,00,46,00,6f,00,6c,00,64,00,65,00,72,00,20,\
  00,61,00,73,00,20,00,56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,20,00,50,00,\
  72,00,6f,00,6a,00,65,00,63,00,74,00,00,00
"Icon"=hex(2):22,00,25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,\
  00,4c,00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,\
  4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,\
  00,73,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,\
  56,00,53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,\
  00,65,00,78,00,65,00,22,00,2c,00,30,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode\command]
@=hex(2):22,00,25,00,55,00,53,00,45,00,52,00,50,00,52,00,4f,00,46,00,49,00,4c,\
  00,45,00,25,00,5c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,00,74,00,61,00,5c,00,4c,00,\
  6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,5c,00,50,00,72,00,6f,00,67,00,72,00,61,00,6d,00,73,\
  00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,74,00,20,00,56,00,\
  53,00,20,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,5c,00,43,00,6f,00,64,00,65,00,2e,00,65,\
  00,78,00,65,00,22,00,20,00,22,00,25,00,56,00,22,00,00,00
```

---

Edit: you can verify I am not haking into your registry by verifying the hex values with this [tool](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) :)

Answer (score 1):

try to find out the Microsoft vs Code files it is some time in the default location and sometimes it is in C:\Users\PAPPU KUMAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code.

and then add it to the vscode.reg(create one) files.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Open files
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Edit with VS Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\PAPPU KUMAR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\PAPPU KUMAR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\PAPPU KUMAR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\PAPPU KUMAR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\PAPPU KUMAR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\PAPPU KUMAR\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Answer (score 1):

An option, `Open with Code Insiders`, is being added to the Insiders Build 1.73, specifically for Windows 11.  See [v1.73 Release Notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_73.md#windows-11-context-menu):

> #### Windows 11 Context menu
>
> In this release, we are adding the `Open with Code Insiders` context
> menu entry to [Windows 11 context
> menu](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/)
> for insiders by default. For users, who had previously opted into the
> context menu when installing the insiders, the entry which would show
> up in the old style menu `Shift + F10` will now be replaced with the
> newer entry when updating to the latest insiders. For others, you
> would need to reinstall insiders and opt-in to enable this menu entry
> in the setup wizard. Due to the issues we have encountered during
> development of this menu entry, we plan to iterate on this feature
> with insiders for a couple of milestones to gain confidence before we
> can push this out to stable release for all Windows 11 users.

[image: Windows 11 context menu: Open with Code Insiders]

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also add the path of **vscode** installation folder in the **`Environment Variable =>  User Variable => Path`** now with the command prompt you just have to type

```bash
code c:\
```

and it will open the `c:\` in **vscode**.

**If you don't want to open `cmd.exe` you can just type `code` before the path, as shown below** [image]

> **You need to surround the path as string `".."` if the path contains space between**

and this will open `c:\Windows` in **vscode**

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of versions here on this page. In order to understand what was really done during the installation, I followed the code of the installer.

The easiest way to solve this issue is by using the installer but if you are using a portable version or whatever reason then basically, it is relevant only for Windows 10 and earlier, but it also works on Windows 11 if you use the old-style menu.

If you are using a version without admin rights then change the `HKLM` to `HKCU`(`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`)

You can put the code in a .reg file or run it manually. The first entry of the file is optional, but I added it as it shows in the code. Needless to say, you need to set the path to your VSCode location.

Please look at [the code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/3e2086be96b29a691d7ad830151195cce407cf0d/build/win32/code.iss#L1272C160-L1272C160) at the relevant line (the link I added it is on lines 1272-1284) if you want to see for yourselves.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\VSCodeContextMenu]
"Title"="Open with Code"

; when you right click a file
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\VSCode]
@="Open with Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""

; when you right click a folder
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\VSCode]
@="Open Folder in Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""

; when you right click a folder while holding shift
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode]
@="Open Folder in Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""

; when you right click the background, not on a particular file or folder.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\shell\VSCode]
@="Open Folder in Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\shell\VSCode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually occurs when the vs code user has standard user role. On VS Code installation admin prompt pops up which means that vs code is installed as admin user. If you ticked the boxes, the shortcuts are added but applied only on admin account which was typed into admin prompt on installation.

Quick workaround is to temporary add the current user (who will use the vs code) to administrators group, uninstall and then install VS Code again with the current user admin rights, and after installation remove the user from the admin group.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode installation directory is `C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` by default.
You can check from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_installation)

Make a install.reg file with this content and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Open files
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Edit with VS Code"
"Icon"="C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click ON a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""
; This will make it appear when you right click INSIDE a folder
; The "Icon" line can be removed if you don't want the icon to appear
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Open Folder as VS Code Project"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Answer (score -1):

**Follow this Steps You will Definitely , Get - Open With Code in Explorer.**

Why you are not getting this ,because You Didn't Add that to visual studio code while you install , **backup Your Projects**, if you have,
hen just follow this steps For Windows User:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio Code From.
   Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features :
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Ygo.jpg)
2. Reinstall Visual studio :
   here You Get/Download : https://code.visualstudio.com/download
3. While install , Stop at **Select Additional Tasks**,
   Tick open with options - 2 boxes which is available at install process,
   complete your installation :
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVtux.png)
4. It's Done , check at explorer. You will find that in explorer :
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT8Tp.png)

You Can Also , Try other methods,
registry Editor - that's complicated -

Answer (score -2):

Open VS Code, Go to Settings, Search Context Menu and Check
[image]