# How to open folder or file with VS Code using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, directory

I'm using Windows 11 and as you may know, it has different context menu when you right click in file explorer. If you want to access full list of options, you have to click "Show more options", and then if you want to open a particular file or folder with VS Code, you have to look for that option in that extended context menu. But as you might have already guessed it, it's tedious and I would like to do that 2 step process with one keyboard shortcut like Ctrl+b. Like, when I press Ctrl+b, it should open the folder I'm in at the moment with VS Code, or, if I highlight a file or folder with mouse click, it should open that file or folder after pressing Ctrl+b. I don't even know if it's possible. I googled it and some guy did it with "Auto hot key" app, but the same didn't work for me. And also, it was a bit buggy and it was closing some open windows. So, if anyone knows a solution, I would be glad to hear.

Comment: find the VSC command that is triggered by a mouse click and determine the context of the focus (editor, list, input,.....) and create keybinding for that command and `when` context, you can give the same key combo many functions if the context is different

Comment: Specifically for Windows 11 (context menu) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74266480/836330 - In the Insiders Build an `Open with Code Insiders` option will be at the top level.  So it is getting closer Stable.